# Repeated axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some data on a contour plot and I need to repeat the x axis. This means that the values on the x axis go from 7 to 2 and back to 7. How can I do that?

Comment: Add your code and data sample, so we can help you.

Comment: That's not possible. But you can let your data go from 0 to 10 and just label 0 as 7, 5 as 2 and 10 as 7.